# How to call a class on a drop-down item tap?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I am trying to make a quiz app in which i want to call `QuestionDisplay()` on a drop down `onchanged` function but it is giving error `"can't be assigned to the parameter type string"`, what does it mean?

I just want to display random question on a tap on drop-down item, like question and something else, but it is not going to the way i just want it to go, kindly guide me that how can it will b possible to display random question on a drop down tap that on tap it will display a random question that i want to define in `QuestionDisplay` class?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
      home: new LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation<double> _iconAnimation;
  AnimationController _iconAnimationController;
  String selectedValues;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _iconAnimationController = new AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: new Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    _iconAnimation = new CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _iconAnimationController,
      curve: Curves.bounceOut,
    );
    _iconAnimation.addListener(() => this.setState(() {}));
    _iconAnimationController.forward();
  }

  //Background Image Code Starts From here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: new Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
        new Image(
          image: new AssetImage('asset/bg.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        new Theme(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(100.0, 10.0, 100.0, 00.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: new AssetImage('asset/I2.png'),
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          data: new ThemeData(
              canvasColor: Colors.blue.shade200,
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              inputDecorationTheme: new InputDecorationTheme()),
          isMaterialAppTheme: true,
        ),
        new Column(
         children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 350.0, 200.0, 0.0)),
            new Text(
              QuestionDisplay(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 24.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                fontFamily: "Georgia",
                color: Colors.grey[300],
              ),

            ),
            new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0,)),
            new DropdownButton<String>(

              hint: new Text('Select Type'),
              value: selectedValues,
              items: <String>[
                "Questions",
                "Something else",
              ].map((String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                    QuestionDisplay();
                 // selectedValues = value.toString();
                });
              },
            ),

          ],

        ),
        ImageRotate(), 
      ]),

    );
  }
}

class ImageRotate extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageRotateState createState() => new _ImageRotateState();
}

class _ImageRotateState extends State<ImageRotate>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController animationController;

  static var rng = new Random();
  double random_number = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    animationController = new AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: random_number.toInt()),
    );

  }

  void move() {
    double random_number = (5 +
        ((rng.nextInt((5 - 1).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil())) /
            4000.0));
    double random_number1 = (4 +
        ((rng.nextInt((5 - 1).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil())) /
            4000.0));


    animationController.duration = Duration(seconds: random_number.toInt());
    animationController.forward(from: -1.0);

    animationController.repeat();
    print(animationController.value);
    print(animationController.value * random_number1);
    animationController.addListener(() {
      this.setState(() {
        animationController.forward();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double random_number3 = (60 +
        ((rng.nextInt((5 - 1).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil() * 1000) +
                rng.nextInt((30 - 10).ceil())) /
            4000.0));

    return new Container(
      height: 150.0,
      width: 150.0,
      padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(110.0, 150.0, 100.0, 420.0),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      child: new AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: animationController,
        child: new GestureDetector(
          child: new Image.asset('asset/5.png'),
          onTap: () {
            move();
          },
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget _widget) {
          return new Transform.rotate(
            angle: animationController.value * random_number3.toInt(),
            child: _widget,
          );
        },
      ),

    );
  }
}
//Animation code Ends from here

class QuestionDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuestionDisplayState createState() => _QuestionDisplayState();
}

class _QuestionDisplayState extends State<QuestionDisplay> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200.0,));
    return new Text(
      "HEllo World"

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Text(
          QuestionDisplay(),
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 24.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
            fontFamily: "Georgia",
            color: Colors.grey[300],
          ),
```

> QuestionDisplay() is the widget not a string.

In this you are passing Widget instead of String for Text widget , Text widget first parameter is String.

And for your logic question:

```
setState(() {
                QuestionDisplay();
             // selectedValues = value.toString();
            });
```

This code is no use you are calling QuestionDisplay which just create instance of the widget but no use of it, you may need to design your widget correctly to achieve your expectation.

You can read this replay , this will give you the idea how to handle the event and update widget.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51033284/3279156

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: For Text widget first parameter is String , you are passing widget in place of string which is not correct. https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html