# Method is not defined in other class

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

Because I want to call the setState Method in the class **"EditProfilePage"**, I had to change it to a statefulWidget:

```
class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();

}

class _EditProfilePageState extends State<EditProfilePage> {

  TextEditingController nameController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController bioController = new TextEditingController();
   File file;

       .
       .
       .

     applyChanges() {
    Firestore.instance
        .collection('insta_users')
        .document(currentUserModel.id)
        .updateData({
      "displayName": nameController.text,
      "bio": bioController.text

    });
  }
 }
```

But now, my class **'Profile_page'** seems to miss the method "applyChanges()" of "EditProfilePage" and throws following error:

> The method 'applyChanges' isn't defined for the class
>   'EditProfilePage'.

Here is the method in **'Profile_Page'**, which calls **applyChanges()** from **'EditProfilePage'**:

```
editProfile() {
    EditProfilePage editPage = new EditProfilePage();

    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(new MaterialPageRoute<bool>(builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return new Center(
        child: new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              leading: new IconButton(
                icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.maybePop(context);
                },
              ),
              title: new Text('Edit Profile',
                  style: new TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
              elevation: 1.0,
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              actions: <Widget>[
                new IconButton(
                    icon: new Icon(
                      Icons.check,
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      editPage.applyChanges();
                      Navigator.maybePop(context);
                    })
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem? I did not forget to import.

Btw I am very new to flutter and just trying to understand dart. Best Regards!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [call method in one stateful widget from another stateful widget - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029655/call-method-in-one-stateful-widget-from-another-stateful-widget-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make significant change to your `EditProfilePage` structure by moving the `applyChanges` function away from `_EditProfilePageState` class:

```
   class EditProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {

   @override
   _EditProfilePageState createState() => _EditProfilePageState();

     static void applyChanges(TextEditingController nameController, TextEditingController bioController) {
      Firestore.instance.collection('insta_users').document(currentUserModel.id).updateData({
      "displayName": nameController.text,
      "bio": bioController.text
      });
     }

   }
```

Then call `applyChanges()` function from inside the function `editProfile()` :

```
  EditProfilePage.applyChanges(nameController, bioController);
```

But you have to make your `TextEditingController` objects which contain the `name` and `bio` visible to the context you are calling from. One way I would suggest is to make them global by defining them under the import section of your code which will enable any inner class to use them.