# how to Call method in one stateful widget from another stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a method called **Counter()** In the homepage StatefullWidget, i want to call this method from my main.dart.

**I am trying to call the method Counter() from my main.dart file. i post the code below**

```
 here is my homepage, class

    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class homepage extends StatefulWidget {
      const homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      _homepageState createState() => _homepageState();
    }
    
    class _homepageState extends State<homepage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container();
      }
      Counter(){
        //I want to call this method from my main.dart file
      }
    }
```

```
   Here is my main.dart file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        Future<void> backgroundhandller(RemoteMessage message) async {
          **Counter()** //I want to call here
            
        }
        
        void main() async {
          FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundhandller);
          runApp(MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: "Taxiyee_Messaging_app",
            home: LoginScreen(),
          ));
        }
```

Comment: I think you can use key for that

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `Counter()` method as a `static` (outside of your `build()` method).

```
static void Counter() {
   //Your code
}
```

and call it by using (remember to import the homepage into the `main.dart` file)

```
Future<void> backgroundhandller(RemoteMessage message) async {
      homepage.Counter();
}
```

[This may be helpful](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#class-variables-and-methods).

Comment: where can i put this. out side of StatefullWidget

Comment: Declare your ```Counter()``` method just above your ```_homepageState```.

Answer (score 0):

The `_homepageState` class is private because of the preceding `_` you can't access it. however you can move the method to the `homepage` class and then you can call it from anywhere you imported it.

also you can still use the counter method inside your `_homepageState` class by using the widget object like this `widget.counter()`

**This would be the end code:**

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  const homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  void count(){
    //I want to call this method from my main.dart file
  }

  @override
  _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    widget.count(); // This how you use it inside your State

    return Container();
  }
  
}
```

Here is how to use it inside the main.dart file

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'homepage.dart';

Future<void> backgroundhandller(RemoteMessage message) async {
  Homepage().count() //call it here or anywhere like this      
}
    
void main() async {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundhandller);
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    title: "Taxiyee_Messaging_app",
    home: LoginScreen(),
  ));
}
```

you notice I've done some changes to the names to follow convention. Classes names start with Capital letters methods/function with small letters.

Comment: But I have   setState(() { });  Method Inside then ChatCounter(), if I Declare my method out side of Build method. how I call  setState(() { })  inside ChatCounter(;  out side of BuildMethod

Comment: I believe you need update a parent widget based on the changes of a child widget. in this case you can use callbacks by passing functions to the child widget constructor. or it would be better to use a central state object.
I just answered your question on calling the method from outside the state.
You can check this similar question here as it covers more scenarios:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029655/call-method-in-one-stateful-widget-from-another-stateful-widget-flutter?rq=1