# how to update one widget from another widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

i'm building flutter app in which user can comment. i want to update the comment list when user post a new comment. at the momentm list is updating but i have to go to another page then come back to update the list. any help would be much appreciatd
p.s i'm new to flutter

```
class NoteDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  const NoteDetail({Key? key, required this.noteModel}) : super(key: key);
  final NoteModel noteModel;


  @override
  State<NoteDetail> createState() => _NoteDetailState();
}

class _NoteDetailState extends State<NoteDetail> {
  //controllers
  final _commentController = TextEditingController();
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final api = CommentApiConfig();
  File? _selectedFile;

  void postComment() async {
    try {
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      );
      var imageUrl = ''
      if (_selectedFile != null) {
        imageUrl = await UploadService.uploadImage(_selectedFile!);
      }
      final commentModel = CommentModel(
        userId: AppData.loggedUserId,
        noteId: widget.noteModel.id!,
        comment: _commentController.text,
        media: imageUrl,
      );
      await api.postComment(commentModel: commentModel);
      await api.getAllCommentByNoteId(noteId: widget.noteModel.id!);
      _commentController.clear();

      if (!mounted) return;
      Navigator.pop(context);
      // AppNavigation.pop();
      setState(() {
        setState(() {

        });
      });

    } catch (e) {
      ErrorDialog(
        error: e,
      ).show(context);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    super.dispose();
    _commentController.clear();
  }

  Widget wrapWithSliver(Widget child) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(child: child);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'Note detail',
          style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
            fontSize: 18,
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          PopupMenuButton<int>(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.more_horiz,
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context) => [
              PopupMenuItem(
                onTap: () {
                  DynamicLinkProvide()
                      .createLink(widget.noteModel.id.toString())
                      .then((value) {
                    print("${value}");
                    Share.share(value);
                  });
                },
                value: 1,
                child: Text(
                  "Share",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
              PopupMenuItem(
                value: 2,
                // row has two child icon and text
                child: Text(
                  "Delete",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                        fontSize: 15,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            offset: const Offset(10, 20),
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 2,
            surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 29, vertical: 0),
        child: CustomScrollView(
          physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(
            parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          ),
          slivers: [
            wrapWithSliver(const SizedBox(height: 20)),
            SliverPadding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 10),
              sliver: wrapWithSliver(
                Text(
                  widget.noteModel.priority.toString(),
                  style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                    color: AppColors.primaryYellow,
                    fontSize: 14,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            wrapWithSliver(Text(
              widget.noteModel.title.toString(),
              style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            )),
            SliverPadding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              sliver: wrapWithSliver(Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  const Card(
                    elevation: 5,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.calendar_month_sharp,
                        color: AppColors.primaryYellow,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(width: 2),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Deadline',
                        style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 14,
                          color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        DateFormat('E, d MMMM')
                            .format(widget.noteModel.deadline!)
                            .toString(),
                        style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ),
            wrapWithSliver(Text(
              'My Todo',
              style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            )),
            SliverPadding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              sliver: wrapWithSliver(Text(
                widget.noteModel.description.toString(),
                style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                  color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              )),
            ),
            if (widget.noteModel.media != "null")
              wrapWithSliver(
                Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                  Text(
                    'Media',
                    style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                      color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      fontSize: 20,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  if (widget.noteModel.media?.isNotEmpty ?? false) ...[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 2.0,
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                          child: Image.network(
                            widget.noteModel.media ?? '',
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            loadingBuilder: (_, child, loadingProgress) {
                              if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                return child;
                              }
                              return Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ] else ...[
                    const Center(child: Text('No Media Available!')),
                  ],
                ]),
              ),
            SliverPadding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
              sliver: wrapWithSliver(Text(
                'VA Comments',
                style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                  color: AppColors.darkTeal,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  fontSize: 22,
                ),
              )),
            ),
            wrapWithSliver(Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: AppTextField(
                maxLines: 1,
                textEditingController: _commentController,
                // textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty || value.trim().isEmpty) {
                    return 'Comment Text is required.';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                hint: 'Comment',
                suffix: IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_formKey.currentState?.validate() ?? false) {
                      postComment();
                      setState(() {});
                    }
                  },
                ),
                fillColor: const Color(0xffefefef),
              ),
            )),
            wrapWithSliver(const SizedBox(height: 20)),
            CommentItem(noteId: widget.noteModel.id!),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my second file in which i defined a comment

```
class CommentItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const CommentItem({Key? key, required this.noteId}) : super(key: key);

  final String noteId;

  @override
  State<CommentItem> createState() => _CommentItemState();
}

class _CommentItemState extends State<CommentItem> {
  final api = CommentApiConfig();
  var isLoading = true;
  var commentResponseModel = <CommentResponseModel>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getAllComments();
  }

  void getAllComments() async {
    try {
      commentResponseModel =
          await api.getAllCommentByNoteId(noteId: widget.noteId);
    } catch (e) {
      ErrorDialog(error: e).show(context);
    }
    isLoading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    if (isLoading) {
      return const SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
      );
    } else {
      return SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (_, i) {
            final comment = commentResponseModel[i];
            return Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    comment.profileImage != null
                        ? CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            radius: 26,
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              comment.profileImage!,
                            ),
                          )
                        : const CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            radius: 26,
                            child: Icon(Icons.person),
                          ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          comment.fullName,
                          style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                          ),
                        ),
                        // if (comment.media!.isNotEmpty)
                        //   Image.network(
                        //     comment.media!,
                        //     height: 100,
                        //     width: 150,
                        //     fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        //     loadingBuilder: (_, child, loadingProgress) {
                        //       if (loadingProgress == null) {
                        //         return child;
                        //       }
                        //       return Center(
                        //         child: Container(
                        //             alignment: Alignment.center,
                        //             color: Colors.white,
                        //             height: 30,
                        //             width: 30,
                        //             child: const CircularProgressIndicator()),
                        //       );
                        //     },
                        //   ),
                        const SizedBox(width: 5),
                        Text(
                          comment.comment,
                          style: textTheme.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 14,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            color: AppColors.darkGrey,
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                const Divider(
                  height: 10,
                  thickness: 1,
                  indent: 10,
                  endIndent: 10,
                  color: AppColors.dividerGrey,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
          childCount: commentResponseModel.length,
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [call method in one stateful widget from another stateful widget - Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029655/call-method-in-one-stateful-widget-from-another-stateful-widget-flutter)

Comment: Don't.  Just don't.  You introduce a coupling that will be difficult to maintain, scale, and test.  Use proper shared-state through one of the many state management solutions (I recommend riverpod).

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use some state management solution like bloc or simple getx.

You can pass the callback function from the parent widget to the child widget and then by calling that function you can do what changes are necessary in your parent widget. But it is not recommended.

Comment: thank you. I'm just new to flutter, which would you recommend me to use?

Comment: As you said you are new in Flutter so I think you can use getx. It's easy to learn.
But when you will be proficient with Flutter and emphasize clean code architecture, you should strongly consider incorporating Cubit (light version of blo) into your development workflow.